# What methods are available to implement a text editor in Java?

Tags: java

What methods are available to implement a text editor in Java?

Comment: Depends on the purpose of your new text editor. Notepad replacement, hex editor or full featured IDE/RAD. Tell us more about your plan.

Answer (score 8):

The [`JTextPane`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) class would be a good start.

The [How to Use Editor Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) and [Using Text Components and Text Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) sections from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) would be a nice to place to take a look at examples and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), a open source java editor for ideas on how exactly to go about building an editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). See [http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ How do I create my own editor?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_editor%3F)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/). Here is a [link](http://www.antonioshome.net/kitchen/netbeans/nbms-standalone.php).

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully integrated [EKit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ekit/) into a Java application, which is a fairly functional HTML text editor.